# C++ to MIPS - Small issue with if statements

Tags: c++, mips

**C++ Program:**

```
 int main()
{
   char string[256];
   int i=0;
   char *result = NULL;  // NULL pointer 

   // Obtain string from user
   scanf("%255s", string);

   // Search string for letter t.
   // Result is pointer to first t (if it exists)
   // or NULL pointer if it does not exist
   while(string[i] != '\0')
   {
      if(string[i] == 't')
      {
         result = &string[i]; 
         break; // exit from while loop early
      }
      i++;
   }

   if(result != NULL)
      printf("Matching character is %c\n", *result);
   else
      printf("No match found\n");
}
```

**MIPS code that I have:**

```
    .globl main

        .text 

# main 
main:

        li $v0,4                # Load value 4 
        la $a0, msg0            # Load array
        syscall                 

        li $v0,8                # Load value 8
        la $a0,string           # Load array
        syscall                 # Syscall

        li $v0,4                # Load immediate value 4 
        la $a0, string          # Load array
        syscall                 # Syscall

        la $t0, string          # array    
        la $t1, result          # array
        lb $t2, result          # array

while:
        lb $t3, 0($t0)          
        beq $t3, $0, if2        # if !=0
        beq $t3, 't', if        # If = "t"
        addi $t0, $t0,1         # i++

        j while                 # Jump to While

if:
        sw $t3, result          # Save result to memory
        li $v0,4                # Load value 4 
        la $a0, found           # Load array
        syscall                 # Syscall
        j exit

        j if2                   # Jump to if2

if2:

        li $v0,4                # Load value 4 
        la $a0, notfound        # Load array
        syscall                 # Syscall
        j exit

exit: 

        li $v0, 10
        syscall # Exit

        .data
        msg0: .asciiz "Enter Word: "
        string: .byte 0:256
        i: .word 0
        result: .word 0
        found: .asciiz "Found!"
        notfound: .asciiz "Not Found"
```

The MIPS code I wrote seems to be working but I think its not following the C++ code structure above.  I also think that I have messed up something with if statements but can't figure out what and how to fix it.  Any suggestion how I can improve it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some details about what you think is wrong with the MIPS code, or how you have "messed up something with if statements"?

Comment: My friend commented on my code that its not following the C++ structure.  I wasn't sure how so that's why I decided to post it here so that someone else might be able to detect it. He is the grader for the class so he is not suppose to give me more details.  I think it has something to do with either if2 or if(result != NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @user2229152 said, you've removed the final check (`if(result != NULL)`) and moved the prints to your `if` and `if2` blocks.

So your assembly code essentially corresponds to this:

```
while(string[i] != '\0')
{
   if(string[i] != 't')
   {
      i++;
   } else
   {
      result = &string[i]; 
      printf("Found!");
      goto exit;
   }
}

printf("Not found");

exit:
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the mips code follows the C code quite closely. The main difference is that it practically inlined the the test at the end of the function into the branch to optimize a branch away. While loops have a tendency to look unintuitive in assembly. They are usually compiled to something that looks more like:

```
if(test) {
    do {
         body;
    } while(test);
}
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I have no idea what u are talking about.  My MIPS code follows the C++ structure but I think I messed up if statements, especially if2.